# Is "you've coming from" a colloquialism?

Tags: word-choice, idioms, colloquialisms, lyrics

In the Take That song, Never Forget, the lyrics run "Never forget where you've coming from". Was that a mistake, or is it a colloquialism (or something else) to say "you've" instead of "you're" in this context?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aha. I've just listened to five different performances on YouTube (that's dedication) and I'm sure it's *"Never forget where you've come 'ere from"* at the beginning of the song, and in later choruses, it's *"Never forget where you're comin' from"*

Have a listen for yourself: http://www.youtube.com/user/TakeThatHD?blend=2&ob=5#p/search/8/GfKSIai0RlU

Comment: I'd go with that interpretation.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that is a transcription (or perhaps a listening) error.
The lyrics sites that I checked couldn't decide whether "Never forget where you're coming from" or "Never forget where you've come here from" was the correct lyric.

"Never forget where you've come in from" would also be a grammatically proper phrase that could all-too-easily be misheard.

Edit: having re-listened to it, I'm pretty sure of the "Never forget where you've come in from" interpretation.

Comment: If you [listen to the song](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OtrNknhuG60#t=2m10s), it sounds *a lot* more like "never forget where you've comin' from" than like "never forget where you're comin' from." It would take access to official lyrics to know for sure.

Comment: I agree; the lyrics sites are hazy on which is actually sung. The original album sounds very much like "you've", while Eoghan Quigg sang "you're" on X Factor. I would therefore happily dismiss this as a quirk of the recording, but for the number of covers and other versions performed where "you've" is clearly sung.